# Read line from file apply regex and write to parquet file scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I have a log file which has log events. I need to read line and apply regex to get the elements from line and write to parquet file. I have an avro schema which has the column definitions.

Could some one guide me one this to proceed.

```
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("SparkApp")
  .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value")
  .getOrCreate()
val rdd = sc.textFile(args(0))
val schemaString = args(1)
val pattern = new Regex(args(2))

val fields = schemaString.split(" ")
  .map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, StringType, nullable = true))
val schema = StructType(fields)

val matches = rdd.map { x => pattern.findFirstMatchIn(x) }.map{ x => x.map{x => x.subgroups}}
val values = matches.map { x => x.map { x => Row(x.toArray) }}
```

in values i'm getting `RDD[Option[Row]]`.
Any suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `RDD[Option[Row]]` because you do regex.Following is the definition of `findFirstMatchIn` and it returns `Option`

```
def findFirstMatchIn(source: CharSequence): Option[Match]
```

To avoid this

```
val matches = rdd.map { x => pattern.findFirstMatchIn(x) }.map { x => x.map { x => x.subgroups }.get }
val values = matches.map { x => x.map { x => Row(x.toArray) } }
```

**Result**

```
RDD[List[Row]]
```

To be defensive, you can think of `getOrElse` instead `get`

You can also think of `flatmap` if you want just `RDD[Row]`